# Need help understanding why this string in grep pulls IP addresses rather than this other string

Tags: bash, grep, ip

The following statement is from a homework question which I tested out and answered, but I'm just not understanding how come this line behaves the way it does and I want to understand why. I realize why this expression is flawed to find an IP address but I don't fully understand why it behaves the way it does since it seems as if the question mark doesn't actually behave as 0 or 1 times in like it's supposed to.

"user@machine:~$ grep -E '[01]?[0-9][0-9]?' "

To my understanding "[01]?" should look for any number 0-1 as indicated by the brackets while the question mark tells grep to look for zero or one instance only and similar with "[0-9]?". Thing is this line will print an unlimited number of digits far exceeding 3 digits. I ruled out that it was due to the 3rd bracket that didn't have a proceeding question mark since it would still print an unlimited amount of digits if I piped an echo or used a testing .txt file full of numbers.

This above example made me than wonder how to find IP's with grep the correct way. So I found countless examples like the following expression for IPv4 octets:

\.(25[0-5]\|2[0-4][0-9]\|[01][0-9][0-9]\|[0-9][0-9]).\

Is this telling me to look for any number 2-5 anywhere from 0-5 times? 0-5 is too many digits for an octet. Is it telling me to look for any number 0-5 up to 25 times? Again that's way too many digits for an octet.  What does \2[0-4][0-9]\ mean in this case? I'm confused about how this expression finds numbers strictly between 1-255?

Comment: `[0-9]` means any digit, from zero to nine (inclusive), the dash in the bracket here denotes the range. `[09]` means either zero or nine.  These are not quantity qualifiers as in `+*?` or curly brace notation.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it this way: `x?[0-9]x?` matches anything which contains a digit because both the `x`:es are optional. You might as well leave them out because they do not constrain the match at all.

`25[0-5]` looks for `25` followed by a digit in the range 0-5. In other words, the expression matches a number in the range 250-255.

The full expression in your example looks for a number in the range 00-255 by enumerating strings beginning with 25, 20-24, etc; though it's incomplete in that it doesn't permit single-digit numbers.

The expression matches a single octet (incompletely), not an entire IP address. Here is a common way to match an IPv4 address:

```
([3-9][0-9]?|2([0-4][0-9]?|5[0-9]?|[6-9])?|1([0-9][0-9]?)?)(\.([3-9][0-9]?|2([0-4][0-9]?|5[0-9]?|[6-9])?|1([0-9][0-9]?)?){3}
```

where the square brackets express character classes which match a single character out of a set, and the final curly braces `{3}` express a repetition.

Some regex dialects (e.g. POSIX `grep`) require backslashes before `|` and `\(` but I have used the extended notation (a la `grep -E` and most online regex exploration tools) which doesn't want backslashes.

Comment: The [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) contains some troubleshooting tips and common beginner questions, as well as many links to more information and other regex resources.